# ng-focus and ng-blur not working with ui-grid-cellNav in Angular UI grid

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to give cell navigation feature to a UI grid using keyboard arrow keys.

For that, "I-grid-cellNav" is there so I am trying to use it in below manner in uiGrid.html file.

```
<div ui-grid="Grid" style="height: 100%;width :100%" class="grid" ui-grid-cellNav ui-grid-edit ui-grid-selection>
```

But after giving ui-grid-cellNav in above code, ng-focus and ng-blur directives are not working in controller below:

```
> columnDefs:[{
>               displayName: '*Event Name',
>               name: 'eventName',
>               width: 150,
>               enableCellEdit: false,
>               cellClass : function(grid,row,col){
>                 return getCellStyle(grid, row,col);
>               },
>               cellTemplate: '<div class="typetext" title="{{row.entity.eventName}}"><input
> ng-disabled="grid.appScope.disableFields" type="INPUT_TYPE"
> ng-click="grid.appScope.startEditing(row.entity.eventName,col,model)"
> ng-focus="grid.appScope.startEditing(row.entity.eventName,col,model)"
> ng-model="row.entity.eventName" typeahead-wait-ms="300"
> typeahead="item for item in
> grid.appScope.getMatchingItems(col.field,row.entity.eventName)"
> class="form-control grid-txtbox"
> ng-blur="grid.appScope.stopEditing(row.entity[col.field],col.field,row)" /></div>'
>             }
```

I am using AngularJS v1.3.17.